# MarkLogic Admin interface does not accept credentials

Tags: marklogic, credentials, admin-interface

We are using MarkLogic 9.0.8.2

It was working fine and then suddenly when i was configuring failover for security database with master & replica forests on multiple nodes, i started getting issue with not accepting credentials.

I looked at logs and found that security database state is open

```
2019-07-03 09:48:36.465 Info: Forest security-01 state changed from recovering to open
2019-07-03 12:45:49.688 Info: Mounted forest security-02-replica remotely on ML03
2019-07-03 09:48:36.465 Info: Forest security-01 state changed from recovering to open
2019-07-03 12:45:49.691 Info: Mounted forest security-03 remotely on ML03
2019-07-03 12:45:49.699 Info: Mounted forest security-01-replica remotely on ML02
2019-07-03 12:45:49.700 Info: Mounted forest security-02 remotely on ML02.
2019-07-03 12:45:52.055 Info: Database Security is online with 3 forests
```

So looking at log, it seems, everything is fine.

so i am not sure why it is not accepting the credentials. How can i retrieve or reset admin password?

I think, i got the cause, i have followed below steps to configure failover on security database

- Created 3 master forests
- Created 3 replicas
- Attached new forests to database, clicked on attach & retire on old by default security forest
- on configuration machine, deselect old security DB and kept selection on retire checkbox
  **And this is where i think problem is, i did not waited for merging to finish :(**
  MarkLogic service is running, will not merge in background?

I have already restarted service, VMs multiple times.

Now question, how to solve (already loaded around 15M data) this? How to attach old security forest for merge to happen

[image]

Comment: Were you using a tool like ml-gradle to do this configuration? Is it possible you changed your password via such a tool unintentionally?

Comment: Thanks Rob S for your reply, No, was doing thru MarkLogic Admin Interface only. And as i am working on jumpbox, so always use copy paste for credentials. BTW, it was working fine till this morning

Comment: Added more info on possible causes in original question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From MarkLogic's knowledgebase

> ### Multiple forests for Security database
>
> We do not recommend configuring multiple forests for the Security
> database, as this can cause failover issues when doing upgrades and
> restarts. Security database should have a single primary forest and
> replicas on all hosts to ensure High Availability.

https://help.marklogic.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/601/0/multiple-forests-for-security-database

It seems possible that you may have detached the security database before the documents were migrated to the other forests. MarkLogic maintains a 'databases.xml' file in the configuration folder that contains details about the forests that are attached among other things. Older versions are also present with a number suffix eg. 'databases_1.xml', 'databases_2.xml'

You could try the following on each node:

1. Stop ML service
2. Navigate to the ML's config directory and rename 'databases.xml' to 'databases_bad.xml'
3. Rename 'databases_1.xml' to 'databases.xml'

Finally, restart ML service on all the nodes and wait for the existing documents to be migrated.

PS: I haven't seen this mentioned on ML knowledge base so I am not sure if this is the recommended approach but I have tried this locally and was able to restore to a previous configuration by renaming the database files.

Comment: Thanks Arnold for your quick response, so now need to see how can i retrieve admin credentials else i need to start from zero. I can only revert only when admin interface is available.

Comment: @ManishJoisar - I have updated my answer with a potential fix

Comment: You may want to reach out to Support, and have them guide you with this. It is easy to mess up when changing those xml config files.

Comment: Thanks Arnold, I was able to follow the steps mentioned by you and can see all forest including security forest  which i retired and detached immediately before it move all its data to other forest. So after data moved, i retired security forest and now everything is fine. Thanks for your solution.